# Add user control to panel on button click

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.NET and struggling with below.

In my button click event I'm trying to add a user control every time a button is clicked. I only ever see one control, I presume I'm just overwriting each time. How do I get it to display each version in the list?

```
     Dim ucMyCtrl As New MyControl

     pnlAddMyControl.Controls.Add(ucMyCtrl )
```

Comment: You need to set the location that you want your usercontrol to be at. As of right now they are stacked ontop of each other.

Comment: You might find that using a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` would help here. You could use one instead of the `Panel` or, if you need other children on that `Panel`, inside the `Panel`. Both those controls will automatically layout all their children and you won't need to set the `Location` manually.

Comment: Hi FlowLayout Worked thanks